# C - Is playing music possible?

Tags: c, console, wav, playback

I am making a text-based adventure game in language C.
I am using CodeBlocks and the game will be a console application.

Is it possible to put a "background music" thingy in the program?
It would make the game much more catchy.

I only know that the music should be in .wav format.
But I have only found C# and C++ solutions for this problem (and the C++ solution was a video on YouTube with very bad quality).

So, if it is possible in C, then can someone tell me how to do it?

It would be greatly appreciated!
(also, I would like the music to replay itself, since it is only 2 minutes long, but I want it to play over and over as long as the program is running).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: libraries! (jazz hands) maybe sdl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no portable ways to play the music in C, which means there are very different solutions for DOS, linux, mac and windows. Here is a quick overview of the methods. All of them are somewhat complex:

- DOS: direct PIT programming via 0x42/0x43 from timer interrupt
- Linux: you need either alsa or pulseaudio libraries, and a background thread to play music. Or just launch media player like sox in the background, but then you must ensure user has it installed.
- Mac OS: I have no idea. I know you can spawn `open file.wav` to play file in the default music player, but this will likely be very annoying to user.
- windows: Good old MCI commands probably require the least number of lines of code. You will have to create a hidden window for MCI interfaces to work.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Can you give me any kind of help on this MCI interface? Even a good site which explains it really well (since I am a beginner programmer) would be very helpful! Thank you!